# React Vitest Error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, vitest

I have a project in react and I want to do unit tests using Vitest, but I'm getting the error:

```
FAIL  src/lib/tests/avatar.test.js [ src/lib/tests/simple.test.js ]
Error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. If you are using JSX, make sure to name the file with the .jsx or .tsx extension.
 ❯ formatError node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:43993:46
 ❯ TransformContext.error node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:43989:19
 ❯ TransformContext.transform node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:41740:22
 ❯ Object.transform node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:44283:30
 ❯ loadAndTransform node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:54950:29
```

I have JSX code within .js files. While renaming them to .jsx or converting the code to pure JS resolves the issue, it's not feasible for me due to the numerous components I have. Despite trying several solutions, nothing has worked. Here's my current setup:

vitest.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    global: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: "./src/lib/tests/setup.js",
    transform: {
      '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'esbuild-jest',
    },
  },
  plugins: [react({
    babel: {
      parserOpts: {
        plugins: ['decorators-legacy'],
      },
    },
  })]
})
```

setup.js

```
import { expect } from 'vitest';
import matchers from '@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers';

expect.extend(matchers);
```

component simple.js

```
import React from "react";

const SimpleMenu = () => {
  return <div>SimpleMenu</div>;
};

export default SimpleMenu;
```

test->simple.test.js

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { it, describe, expect } from "vitest";
import SimpleMenu from "./simple";

describe("SimpleMenu", () => {
  it("Must render correctly:", () => {
    const { container } = render(SimpleMenu);
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

});
```

versions and script of package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.14.0",
},
"scripts": {
    "test": "vitest",
    "test:coverage": "vitest run --coverage"
    "test:ui": "vitest --ui",
 },
"devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "4.0.4",
    "@vitest/coverage-v8": "0.34.3",
    "@vitest/ui": "0.34.3",
    "vite": "4.4.9",
    "vitest": "0.34.3"
 }
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: On windows? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/powerrename or https://www.den4b.com/products/renamer

Comment: thanks, but, although I could do the rename in a similar way, I do not see it feasible as it may affect other areas where the component is being called

Comment: You cant have jsx code in js files.J SX is not a valid JavaScript as they are embedded in HTML elements.